# Data structure - run-time and Asymptotic bounds

Tags: math, data-structures, big-o, logarithm

if a>0 is a fixed variable, Prove then: lg(n+a) = Θ(lg n)

please advice.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that f(n) = Θ(g(n)), you need to prove that there is a nonzero k such that

> lim (n → ∞) f(n) / g(n) = k

In your case, we want to show that

> lim (n → ∞) lg(n + a) / (lg n)

This is an indeterminate form of type ∞ / ∞, so we can apply [l'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and take the derivative of the numerator and denominator to get

> lim (n → ∞) lg(n + a) / (lg n) =
>
> lim (n → ∞) (1 / n + a) / (1 / n) =
>
> lim (n → ∞) n / (n + a)

This again is an indeterminate form, so applying l'Hôpital's rule gives

> lim (n → ∞) n / (n + a)
>
> = lim (n → ∞) 1 / 1
>
> = 1

Therefore, there is a nonzero constant (namely 1) such that the limit of lg(n + a) / lg n as n goes to infinity equals that constant, and therefore lg(n + a) = Θ(lg n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! i'll refer similar to math in the future.